# Swift: Initial Capacity of an Array, ReserveCapacity(), and Avoiding Reallocs

Tags: arrays, swift, performance, memory, realloc

Suppose I have this:

```
var collection: Array<String> = []
```

What is the *initial* capacity of `collection` once Swift allocates it? I am interested in preventing reallocs (which are expensive). I understand Swift's geometric growth strategy for reallocating capacity automatically as I need more slots in the Array. I also understand the pitfalls of continuously calling `reserveCapacity()` instead of allowing the normal geometric growth.

But if the initial capacity is `2` or some other low number and I KNOW that I am going to be adding, say, 10 items to `collection`, would I better served from a performance standpoint by doing:

```
var collection: Array<String> = []
collection.reserveCapacity(10)
```

To avoid the reallocs for `4`, `8`, and `16` items as I append items to the Array?

**NOTE**: Before you tell me not to worry about it because the performance difference is very slight, this is a contrived case. In reality I have thousands of objects that are going to have a `collection` property and each `collection` is going to contain about 5-10 items, which will be appended incrementally and are not known at the time the Array is created. There are potentially many thousands and thousands of reallocs involved.

Comment: I should add that I'm a longtime Objective-C developer and I'm migrating code where I used NSMutableArray's -initWithCapacity: method to make sure I didn't hit reallocs. I'm wondering what the best practice is for Swift from a performance standpoint.

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think reserving capacity will make such a difference in your code considering that the string can be of any length.

Comment: Is your question about initial capacity? If you just did `collection.capacity` it would be 0 / @Bryan

Comment: @newDev Well, my fundamental question is: what's the best strategy to avoid reallocs? In ObjC I knew what that was. In Swift, I'm less clear on how the compiler is allocating memory for this Array when it's initialized. Surely it doesn't allocate ZERO memory at initialization, even though the capacity is reported as zero?

Comment: @leoDabus Interesting. I know Strings in Swift are value types, but I confess I'm not an expert on how they're stored in a Swift Array. I could have sworn I read pointers are used under the hood and then the String is recreated for the copy-on-write semantics when its not uniquely referenced. I'm just looking for the most performant approach here where I'm creating thousands of small arrays and incrementally populating them with a few items.

Comment: @Bryan, from [documentation of `Array.capacity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1538388-capacity): "The total number of elements that the array can contain without allocating new storage." And, though `String` are value types, they are still allocated on the heap, afaik. So, I'd say, the best strategy is to reserve capacity to the most likely array size, and then let it grow geometrically if more elements are needed.